# Como criar um script para automatizar troca de link no HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

estou realizando manutenção em um sistema que possui em uma página centenas de links da seguinte forma:

```
<li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
```

Note que há um texto fora da tag `a`. O que desejo fazer, colocar esse texto dentro da tag `a` com o seu suposto href, o exemplo acima ficaria assim:

```
<li> <a href="http://exemplo.com"> Revista alvo </a> </li>
```

Estou fazendo essa troca na mão mas há centenas e centenas de links, o que torna cansativo a tarefa. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer um script para realizar essa tarefa? Pode ser em qualquer linguagem, `PHP`, `JS` etc. Tentei ser o mais claro possível,caso não entendam irei tentar explicar novamente, preciso de ajuda pois é urgente, please!

Comment: Usando o Sublime vc faria isso de boa, ele tbm usa expressões regulares para selecionar areas, usei varias vezes essa ideia

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como eu faria @WeesSmith? Não manjo de regex

Comment: Pesquisa: `<li>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)<a(.*?)>(.*?)+<\/li>$` e o replace: `<li><a$2>$1</a></li>` algo assim, veja esse exmplo: https://regexr.com/3pedc

Answer (score 4):

**Atualização:** Caso não queira abrir arquivo por arquivo, você pode criar um script PHP para varrer um diretório a procura de arquivo HTML ou outro caso queira. Veja:

Esse script será executado através do *Terminal / PowerShell*, então receberá um parâmetro o qual será o diretório a ser varrido. Utilize a função [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) para varrer o diretório, ela irá receber um parâmetro que será `"{$Dir}/*.html"` e irá retornar um array caso tenha encontrado algo, se não encontrar, retornara um array vazio e `false` em caso de erro.

> Antes de utilizar o script abaixo, faça um backup!

```
// Conta quantos argumentos foi informado.
// O primeiro argumento sempre será o nome do arquivo.
$CountArgs = count($argv);

// Verifica se é menor que 2
if ($CountArgs < 2) {
  echo "Informe um diretório!\n\n";
  exit(0);
}
// Verifica se o argumento é um diretório.
else if ( !is_dir($argv[1]) ) {
  echo "O parâmetro informado não é um diretório!\n\n";
  exit(0);
}
// Guarda o argumento na variável.
$Dir = $argv[1];

// Varre o diretório atrás de arquivos html
// depois percorre a array e executa a função.
foreach (glob("{$Dir}/*.html") as $arquivo) {
  alterar_links($arquivo);
}

function alterar_links($Arquivo) {
  // Lê o arquivo, e guarda o conteúdo na variável
  $Conteudo = file_get_contents($Arquivo);
  // Faz a busca usando a expressão regular
  // e modifica usando um callback
  $Alteracoes = preg_replace_callback("|<li>([\w\s]+)<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/li>|",
    function($retorno) {
      return "<li><a{$retorno[2]}>{$retorno[1]}</a></li>";
    },
    $Conteudo);
  // Abre o arquivo em modo escrita
  $arquivo = fopen($Arquivo,'w+');
  // Escreve as alterações no arquivo
  fwrite($arquivo, $Alteracoes);
  // Fecha
  fclose($arquivo);
}
```

> **Importante**: Veja que, ao fazer a alteração, não estou deixando espaço entre a tag `li` e a tag `a`:  `<li><a{$retorno[2]}>{$retorno[1]}</a></li>`. Fazendo assim, caso o script leia novamente o arquivo, ele não faz nenhuma alteração.

#### Referências:

- [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php)
- [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)
- [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php)
- [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php)
- [`fwrite`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php)
- [`fclose`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fclose.php)

---

#### Sublime Text

Você pode utilizar Expressões Regulares para agilizar o processo, veja:

```
<li>([\w\s]+)<a(.*?)>(.*?)<\/li>$
```

#### Explicação:

- `(.*?)`: Captura o texto dentro tag "a" incluindo o fechamento da tag
- `<a(.*?)>`: Captura os atributos da tag "a"
- `([\w\s]+)`: Captura o texto antes da tag "a"

Para utilizar no Sublime Text, aperte `CTRL+H` depois `ALT+R` para ativar a pesquisa por Expressões Regulares, no campo Find coloque o código acima, já no campo Replace:

```
<li><a$2>$1</a></li>
```

#### Explicação:

- **$1**: Coloca o texto capturado antes da tag "a"
- **$2**: Coloca os atributos capturados da tag "a"

Observe que utilizei `[\w\s]+` ao invés de `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` porque assim você recupera tudo que estiver antes, já `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` ira capturar apenas letras, números e os espaços.

[image: Funcionando]

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, consegui resolver com o script abaixo que obtive dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339387/how-to-create-a-script-to-automate-link-exchange-in-html?noredirect=1#comment87708488_50339387) do stackoverflow internacional.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<ul id="linksList">
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>
  <li> Revista alvo <a href="http://exemplo10.com"> http://exemplo.com </a> </li>

  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="changeIt">Change</a>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){     
      $("#changeIt").click(function(){
        $("#linksList li").each(function(){
          txt = $(this).text().split(' http://')[0].trim();
          lnk = $(this).children('a').text(txt)
          $(this).html(lnk)
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```